# textarea as list

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Im trying to make 2 side by side text areas, with 2 buttons between them, one that adds an item from a selected line in the left textarea to the textarea on the right, the other to remove a selected item from the list on the right. Basically, a 'line selected' function is where Im failing. Any ideas?

Comment: why dont you use multiple select for this ?

Comment: aha, hadnt used 'multiple' in my googling, found select="multiple" quickly, this is what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can put each item in span/paragraph tag and use break line if necessary to keep each item on a separate line, then you can put a onclick event on the individual span tags. Would this help?